# Node is not shutting down on ros::ok()

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Mine is just a noob question about the expected behaviour of ros::ok() function.
I've written this very simple piece of code :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "bot");
    ros::NodeHandle nh("~");

    ros::Publisher odo_pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::JointState>("odometry", 1000);
    ros::Subscriber cmd_sub = nh.subscribe(sub.c_str(), 1000, chatterCallback);

    // Define the odometry msg
    sensor_msgs::JointState msg;
    msg.header.frame_id="bot";
    msg.position.resize(4);
    msg.velocity.resize(4);
    msg.effort.resize(4);

    while( ros::ok())
    {
        ROS_INFO("In loop %d",ros::ok());

        msg.header.stamp=ros::Time::now();
        odo_pub.publish(msg);
        ros::spinOnce();
    }
    ROS_INFO("Exit");

    return 0;
}
```

Should the node exit when I Ctrl-c the ros framework (by killing the terminal on which roscore has been started)?
Thanks!

P.S. I'm running ROS hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187243/node-is-not-shutting-down-on-ros::ok()/) by [RagingBit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3460/ragingbit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 706 on 2014-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

do `Ctrl-c`  on terminal where your node is running (not roscore terminal).

you need to call `ros::shutdown()` to shutdown your node.

you use `ros::master::check()` in code to check.

thanks to http://answers.ros.org/question/36733/check-if-roscore-is-started-in-c/?answer=36737#post-id-36737

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RagingBit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3460/ragingbit/) on 2014-07-21**:
That works.
Anyway, I was wondering if there is a way to check from my node if roscore has been turned off, in order to terminate the node as well. Checking on ros::ok() seems not to be working like that...

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-21**:
you use  ros::master::check() thanks to http://answers.ros.org/question/36733/check-if-roscore-is-started-in-c/?answer=36737#post-id-36737

**Comment by [RagingBit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3460/ragingbit/) on 2014-07-21**:
Yes, that was what I was looking for.
Thanks!